# Unsure how to get pressure data from MCP3424

Tags: datalogging, pressure, data

I am having trouble reading data from an MCP3424 chip, specifically the one from this website:

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/general-purpose-adcs/6696086/

I have a pressure transducer that connects to the MCP3424 chip. The chip is then connected to a NodeMCU 1.0. Schematics are attached.

The pressure transducer comes from here:

https://www.edwards.com/gb/devices/pressure-monitoring/transducer?WT.ac=eu_truwave

It is run into a 9-pin VGA adapter

I am new to this kind of stuff, and I do not know what code is needed on the NodeMCU to read the data coming in from the pressure transducer via the MCP3424 chip. My code currently contains code from here:

https://github.com/bersch/MCP3424

My code is set to upload the error message I am getting from the MCP3424 to a spreadsheet so I can read the error. The error I get is "i2c". I am not sure what that means. I have tried contacting the author of the code but I have not received a response in a few weeks. I simply want to read the pressure I am getting from the pressure transducer from the MCP3424 chip.

Some useful information about the MCP3424 chip can be found here:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22088b.pdf

If anyone can provide any guidance, code, or helpful advice, that would be extremely appreciated.

Link to my post on the arduino forum, which includes my code, is here:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=588831.0

Thank you.

Comment: my bet is on a wrong I2C address. run the I2C scanner sketch and adjust any hard-coded value on the sensor demo sketch once you identify the module. If it doesn't show up un the scanner, try adjusting the wires.

Comment: I ran the i2c scanner and all I get is a bunch of unknown errors at every address...what does this mean about the board?

Comment: It means it's hooked up to the MCU wrong, you forgot the I2C pullups (sometimes they can be ignored, sometimes not) or it doesn't have enough voltage/current. It's possible the module or board is defective, but that's a lot rarer than user error.